# Is it possible to get CSS style values in Rvest?

Tags: css, r, rvest

Is it possible to get color codes and other css styles in `Rvest`?
For example, from [Color:Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color) there is word *Help:Using colors*, how can I find the color code '#0b0080' after using `rvest::read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color')` ? Looking for something similiare to getCssValue from Selenium.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘rvest’ queries static HTML documents. It does not parse or apply CSS information. So no, it cannot tell you the elements’ style information. At best it can tell you if an element has a static `style` attribute. But most styling isn’t applied this way.

There are other libraries, such as [‘rselenium’](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium), which emulate the evaluation of a website in an actual browser. This is mostly used to crawl dynamically generated web contents, but it should also apply stylesheets, so there may well be a way of retrieving style information using that route.

If there is no direct way for this, at worst you could use ‘rselenium’ to execute the [`Window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) JavaScript function on your target element.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In RSelenium you can use elem$getElementValueOfCssProperty